# How to (selectively) hide margin notes?

Tags: marginpar

Consider the following LaTeX code, which contains an index entry `my index`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{showidx}
\begin{document}
Hello, world!\index{myindex}
\end{document}
```

This typesets as follows, with the index keyword shown in the margin:

[image: Show index]

If the line `\usepackage{showidx}` is deleted or commented out:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
% \usepackage{showidx}
\begin{document}
Hello, world!\index{myindex}
\end{document}
```

the index keyword disappears from the margin:

[image: Hide index]

A similar mechanism exists for labels using the `showlabels` package:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{showlabels}
\begin{document}
Hello, world!\label{mylabel}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Show labels]

whereas deleting or commenting out the line `\usepackage{showlabels}` produces, as before:

[image: Hide labels]

**Question**

Is there a similar mechanism for margin notes? Consider, for example, the following piece of LaTeX code containing a margin note:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
Hello, world!\marginpar{A margin note.}
\end{document}
```

This code typesets as follows:

[image: Show margin note]

Is it possible to easily hide all margin notes? More intricately, is it possible to assign identifiers to margin notes (in such a way that several notes can share a single identifier), and then to hide only those notes associated with certain identifiers?

**A putative example**

A putative piece of LaTeX code in which margin notes are assigned identifiers:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-4]\marginpar[tempnote]{1st margin note}

\lipsum[2][1-4]\marginpar{2nd margin note}

\lipsum[3][1-4]\marginpar[tempnote]{3nd margin note}
\end{document}
```

This would produce:

[image: Show all notes]

Now the addition of the putative line `\usepackage{hidemarginpar}[tempnote]` to the preamble:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{hidemarginpar}[tempnote]
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-4]\marginpar[tempnote]{1st margin note}

\lipsum[2][1-4]\marginpar{2nd margin note}

\lipsum[3][1-4]\marginpar[tempnote]{3nd margin note}
\end{document}
```

would produce:

[image: Hide selected notes]

Comment: @campa: Fine by me. I'm not married to the name of the command. I only care about the functionality and the ease of use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea of having something like

```
\usepackage{hidemarginpar}[tempnote]
```

is difficult to realize, because one should make `\marginpar` aware of this "label" (with all the risks coming from the redefinition of a kernel macro). It is better to have code to define your new margin notes from scratch.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\newmarginstuff}[1]{%
   \expandafter\@ifdefinable\csname @my@marg@#1\endcsname
      {\expandafter\let\csname @my@marg@#1\endcsname=\iftrue}%\fi
}

\newcommand*{\includemarginstuff}[1]{%
   \@bsphack\expandafter\let\csname @my@marg@#1\endcsname=\iftrue\@esphack
} %\fi

\newcommand*{\excludemarginstuff}[1]{%
   \@bsphack\expandafter\let\csname @my@marg@#1\endcsname=\iffalse\@esphack
} %\fi

\newcommand*{\marginstuff}[2][]{%
   \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
   \else
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
   \fi
   {\marginpar{#2}}%
   {\csname @my@marg@#1\endcsname\marginpar{#2}\fi}%
}

\makeatother

\newmarginstuff{foo}
\newmarginstuff{baz}

\begin{document}

\parskip2ex

Text text text text text text text
\marginstuff[foo]{1st foo}
text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text

Text text text text text text text
\marginstuff{generic}
text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text

\excludemarginstuff{foo}
Text text text text text text text
\marginstuff[foo]{2nd foo}
text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text

Text text text text text text text
\marginstuff[baz]{1st baz}
text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: By the way, is there a simpler answer if all I want to do is hide all margin notes unconditionally?

Comment: @EvanAad Well, you can just do `\renewcommand\marginpar[2][]{}`.