# How to achieve automatically non-overlapping margin notes with the KOMA-Script document classes?

Tags: koma-script, marginnote

With the [`Memoir`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoir) document class the vertical position of margin notes specified via `\marginpar` is flexible so that adjacent notes are prevented from overlapping:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1]%
\marginpar{Hello, world!}%
\marginpar{Bonjour, monde!}%
\lipsum[1][2-4]

\end{document}
```

[image: Adjacent marginpars with the Memoir document class]

Contrary to this, with the [`KOMA-Script`](https://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) document classes adjacent margin notes specified via `\marginnote` (of the [`marginnote`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/marginnote) package) overlap:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1]%
\marginnote{Hello, world!}%
\marginnote{Bonjour, monde!}%
\lipsum[1][2-4]

\end{document}
```

[image: Adjacent marginnotes with the KOMA-Script document class]

(Note: the `KOMA-Script` code needs to be compiled twice in order to work properly. And, by the way, I use LuaLaTeX.)

How can the non-overlapping behavior of margin notes exhibited by the `Memoir` document class be emulated in the context of the `KOMA-Script` document classes?

Comment: I don't see anything in the KOMA documentation about using \marginnotes instead of \margnpar (except warning about the overlap).  \margnipar is standard LaTeX, not peculiar to memoir.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: You're right, however I need to use `marginnote` rather than `marginpar` because of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/604709/21685) problem. It would have been better if I'd compared `marginnote`'s behavior to `marginpar`'s behavior in the context of `KOMA-Script` rather than comparing `marginnote`'s behavior in the context of `KOMA-Script` to `marginpar`'s behavior in the context of `Memoir`.

Comment: Presumably putting \marginnote next to a float or theorem won't overlap anything, and you can use \marginpar otherwise (in outer par mode).  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215322/multiple-marginnote-commands-on-the-same-line-in-math-environment

Comment: @JohnKormylo: This would have been a good solution had I not also wanted to assign tags to margin notes in order to be able to selectively format the notes based on their tags, as explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/604347/21685) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/604979/21685). If you feel very determined to help me solve a problem related to margin notes, the question at the latter link has yet to be fully answrered (there's a hint by Ulrike Fischer, but I'd appreciate a full answer).

Comment: Not really, but I keep wanting to improve https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215322/multiple-marginnote-commands-on-the-same-line-in-math-environment to use saveboxes and macros instead of dimen and count registers.  Just never get around to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well manually you can use an offset:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1]%
 \marginnote{Hello, world!}%
 \marginnote{Bonjour, monde!}[2\baselineskip]%
\lipsum[1][2-4]
\end{document}
```

You could also try the scrlayer-notecolumn package which creates one large note column:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum,scrlayer-notecolumn}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1]
\makenote{Hello, world!}\makenote{Bonjour, monde!}
\lipsum[1][2-4]
\end{document}
```